# How to Sum tables tds data in Jquery Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery

I want to store from view html page table td data list into a text box sum of total marks or obtained marks

```js
function CalculateTotalMarks() {
    var tblbody = $("#tableStudentRecords").find("tbody");
    tblbody.find("tr").each(function () { 
      var  totalresult = $(this).find("td:eq(1) input[type=text]").val();
        $("#txttotal").val(totalresult);
    });
}
```

Comment: show code of table structure

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
function CalculateTotalMarks() {
            var tblbody = $("#tableStudentRecords").find("tbody");
            var totalresult = 0;                
            tblbody.find("tr").each(function () {
                totalresult += parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(1) input[type=text]").val());

            });
            $("#txttotal").val(totalresult);
        }
```

Comment: its showing Nan in (#txttotal) in textbox